# nodejs grunt can't be uninstalled

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-7, gruntjs, npm

I don't know what I am doing wrong. :(

I tried running `npm uninstall -g grunt` and `npm uninstall -g grunt-cli` multiple times but no matter where I am, every time I call the command "grunt" in CMD I get the line `"grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.9)"`

I tried installing grunt-cli using `npm install -g grunt-cli` but even though it said it installed version **0.1.13** whenever I called grunt it kept saying `"grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.9)"`

I checked my system path but couldn't see anything related to grunt except for node itself.

edit: if I'll uninstall node and reinstall it will it fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you run `which grunt`?

Comment: I love you! it was in AppData/Roaming/npm. now the question is how do I get rid of it and what caused it to install there?

Comment: Ok, I guess globally installed modules are supposed to be installed in AppData/Roaming/npm and there's noting to do about it if you want the functions to actually be global. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling node completely and now installing and uninstalling grunt-cli works perfectly